# adaptive-images ai-cache empty

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have loaded adaptive-images following their guide lines but my ai-chache is empty and file sizes remain obviously as original. I have checked my htaccess etc but cannot see the problem. my coding is as follows:
in html5 head
            `enter code here`document.cookie='resolution='+Math.max(screen.width,screen.height)+'; path=/';

in htaccess

```
php_flag display_errors on
ErrorDocument 404 /error-pages/page_error.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On

  # Adaptive-Images -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  # Add any directories you wish to omit from the Adaptive-Images process on a new line, as follows:
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ignore-this-directory
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !and-ignore-this-directory-too

  # Only applies to folder adaptive-images
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} adaptive-images

  # don't apply the AI behaviour to images inside AI's cache folder:
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ai-cache

  # Send any GIF, JPG, or PNG request that IS NOT stored inside one of the above directories
  # to adaptive-images.php so we can select appropriately sized versions

  RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php

  # END Adaptive-Images -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</IfModule>
```

and loaded adaptive-images.php in root with config as

```
$resolutions   = array(1382, 992, 768, 480); // the resolution break-points to use (screen widths, in pixels)
$cache_path    = "ai-cache"; // where to store the generated re-sized images. Specify from your document root!
$jpg_quality   = 75; // the quality of any generated JPGs on a scale of 0 to 100
$sharpen       = TRUE; // Shrinking images can blur details, perform a sharpen on re-scaled images?
$watch_cache   = TRUE; // check that the adapted image isn't stale (ensures updated source images are re-cached)
$browser_cache = 60*60*24*7;
```

all else as per download.